# Wordpress SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a custom post type (information) with custom taxonomy (sender) :
My terms are :

```
- Sender 1 (id 113)
- Sender 2 (id 114)
- Expired (id 132)
```

With SQL Query, I would like to return all posts where "expired" not checked.
One post can have "Sender 1" and "Expired" as checked.

In MySQL table (term_relationships), I have :

```
object_id and term_taxonomy_id
```

Here is my code :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_type = 'information' and post_status = 'publish';";
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach($posts as $information){
$infoId = $information->ID;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM relationships WHERE object_id = '".$infoId."' AND term_taxonomy_id = 113 OR term_taxonomy_id = 114;";
```

After, I'm lost because I have one line per `term_id`. For example :

```
Object_id | term-taxonomy_id
20145     | 113
20145     | 132
20651     | 113
20365     | 114
```

So I would like to display only 20651 and 20365 because 20145 is checked as 132.

Some one can help me?

Comment: Why did you use `;` double times in your sql at the end

Comment: To close my query and my php :) (i do that because sometimes i copy/paste into PHPMyAdmin to see the result and i can have lot of lines). My SQL Query works, but i don't know how to remove id 132 (expired posts)

Comment: Have you tried get_posts() function by passingTaxonomy Parameters ?

Comment: get_posts() function works with my shortcode. But i need this for mailpoet and my newsletter cand read "get_posts()".

Comment: Forget about the php stuff for now, and instead see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry i'm sorry but i dont understand ...

Comment: In which case, we're stuck :-(

Comment: @Strawberry i find a solution with multiple query and comparation :)